# C:\documents and settings\user\windows on XP. where is it? can not find

Tags: crystal-reports, windows-xp

trying to copy some files to  C:\documents and settings\user\windows\crystal\ but can not find such directory  C:\documents and settings\user\windows ????
help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try enable viewing of hidden folders and files in the controll-panel and if the folder still isn't showing it simply does not exist

Comment: it was done before the question. folder still isn't showing. strange how microsoft gives problem solution while even folder does not exits.